# Batch file leaves vbscript program open in Wordpad. Why?

Tags: file, vbscript, batch-file

My batch file contains a START command that runs a short vbscript program. When the batch file completes, the code of the vbscript program is shown in an open Wordpad window. This only started happening after we converted to Windows 7. Never happened under XP. Why does this happen and how can I prevent it? I have done extensive internet searching and come up with nothing.

Here is batch file:

```
@echo off
cls
echo.
echo Copying Latest Version of FREDS Database ...
echo.
xcopy "\\sstore02\S-Drive.OOD\OPI\FREDS\FREDS.mdb" "K:\FREDS\" /i /q /y
echo.
echo If you see "1 File(s) copied" then the copy was successful
echo.
echo Copying Shortcut Installer ...
echo.
xcopy "\\sstore02\S-Drive.OOD\OPI\FREDS\FREDS-Shortcut.vbs" "K:\FREDS\" /i /q /y
echo.
echo If you see "1 File(s) copied" then the copy was successful
echo.
echo Adding Shortcut icon to Desktop ...
echo.
Start K:\FREDS\FREDS-Shortcut.vbs
echo.
pause
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `cscript` instat of `start`.

```
cscript /nologo K:\FREDS\FREDS-Shortcut.vbs
```

The option `/noscript` hides the version of cscript in the output.

Comment: To explain more, you are getting the default behavior for the .vbs extension as setup on your machine. Basically it does the same as if you double-clicked the file. `csript` is what will actually run the script for you.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad is the registered program for the VBS extension on your machine.

Right click a VBS file and select `Open With` and then navigate to `cscript.exe` in `c:\windows\system32 folder` usually.  Select the checkbox to always use that program and then the start command will work with VBS scripts and Cscript.

Comment: You can already tell that this is copied over from a network path from the question, this is probably run on multiple machines. This is a hack/work-around, not a proper solution.

Comment: David M says `"This only started happening after we converted to Windows 7. Never happened under XP."` which implies that he is using it on one machine.

Comment: +1 for answering this boring question. The quality is even too low for superuser, though.